# How can I install php version 7.4 on mac osx 10.11 El Capitan?

Tags: php, version, osx-elcapitan

I tried to install php 7.4 on my mac osx without homebrew, because I am not able to update homebrew anymore.

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.4
```

I get the error

> Did or could not download package: 7.4-frontenddev

Comment: try with homebrew: 'brew install php@7.4'

Comment: @JorgeMiguelSanchez it was successfully installed. But if I enter now `php -v` it shows `PHP 7.3.8`

Comment: you can install the [php switcher script](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-bigsur-apache-multiple-php-versions) and holds multiple php versions. Then only needs to run 'sphp 7.4' to select the 7.4 version

Comment: I installed it already. I wrote `sphp 7.4` . I get a success message but still `PHP 7.3.8`

Comment: Oh, I had to restart terminal and then it worked!

Comment: Can you post your answer, because  it worked

Comment: This question has NOT been answered, as it asks for OS 10.11 (El Capitan) and the question ("How can I easily switch between PHP versions on Mac OSX?") does not ask for 10.11. So I don't understand, why it is a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eyeballing the source for that install script, it looks like when you pass in `7.4`, you're telling the script to get PHP 7.4. Unfortunately, it looks like [the project has been deprecated as of November 30th](https://php-osx.liip.ch), so I suspect they don't have a version 7.4. If you change that `7.4` to `7.3`, it might work.

If there's something specific you need in PHP 7.4 or later, and this script was the *only* thing that worked, you might be out of luck unless you can use a container or VM locally. Something like [this](https://github.com/kibria4/docker-compose-php7.4) might get you unblocked.

Comment: that is sad news? Really no chance?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell, that's the error the packaging script will give you if the version you specified is not available.